# Universal application error

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal

I'm trying to realize an universal application (for iPhone/iPad), and I'd like to use the same UIViewController to set up the behaviour for both of the devices.

I got a surprising error at launch time, which is :

```
2010-07-15 11:31:03.420 AppUniverselle[2761:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7000670> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myLabel.'
2010-07-15 11:31:03.421 AppUniverselle[2761:207] Stack: (
    29291611,
    2421585161,
  ...
    2727445,
    2764719,
    8884,
    8738
)
```

I can't figure out where I failed. Furthermore, to avoid any typo problem, I restarted the project, but it ends on the same error.

The main surprising point is that the application *works fine* on the iPad simulator, but not on the iPhone one. Perhap's there is a problem with the iPhone simulator ?

Does someone know the answer of this question or ever heard about that kind of problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an outlet called `myLabel` in your NIB file, but there's no such outlet in your view controller instance.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but here's the file : 

http://pastebin.ca/1900946

And I can see the property when I look thru the inspector for the NIB file ...

That's why I'm quite surprised :)

Comment: @Rob: well, that's what the error says. Some checks: 1. Did you pick the right class for your view controller in IB? 2. Did you synthesize the property? Check all your NIBs.

Comment: I forgot something : the application works fine when I use the iPad as target ...

But I'm checking NIBs & properties, I'll keep you in touch if I find something.